# C Readline Function Not Working

Tags: c

I'm reading the *BigNerdRanch book on Objective-C* and it's running me through how to take lines into `stdin` in regular C. For some reason, the example code that's supposed to run with `readline` duplicating input (small bug) is not functioning. It builds successfully but after taking input in which if I type `Mikey` it displays `MMiikkeeyy`,

I get:

```
(lldb) IMPLICIT DECLARATION OF FUNCTION READLINE IS Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x20000)
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Who is cool? ");
    const char *name = readline(NULL);
    printf("%s is cool!\n\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This probably means that `readline()` is not declared in `<stdio.h>`. You need to import the proper library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include the header file where `readline()` is declared. Therefore the
compiler assumes that the function returns `int`. This is the reason for the crash at
runtime.

If you use the GNU readline library then add

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
```

to your code. But from your question I assume that you are compiling with Xcode on OS X.
OS X has a "libedit" library which has a "readline wrapper". In that case you only 
include

```
#include <editline/readline.h>
```

The duplicate input (MMiikkeeyy) is probably a problem of the debugger console.
It should work correctly if you start your program from the command line.

Comment: Needed to include extra headers to get it to work! specifically: #include <readline/readline.h>

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Who is cool? ");
    char name[50];
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("%s is cool!\n\n", name);
    return 0;
}
```

The code above does what you desire.

There were two problems with your code

1. There is no function called readline. the function that reads
   characters from standard input is called scanf. the Function takes 2
   parameters a format like %s which means you want to read a string of
   characters and the variable you want to store the characters in.
2. There was also a problem with your variable definition. You have do
   declare it as an array with [size] after the name so you can store
   more than one character.

Hope this helps and for a good c resource see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/)

Comment: `const char *name[50];` is wrong. You'd want `char name[50];`

Comment: thanks didn't notice i just copied the op's code editing

Answer (score 0):

For me when compiling to inclue `readline`, the `include`'s weren't enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
```

I had to link to `readline`:

```
gcc readline_prog.c -o readline_prog -g -Wall -Wextra -lreadline
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783204/1230086) some may need to provide additional paths to the compiler aswell.